# UIPickerView stopped spinning - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I need to make an app that runs a certain code when the UIPickerView stopped spinning. Is there a way to check if the picker view stopped spinning?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by stopped spinning? you mean, stopped because the user has picked an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `didSelectRow` is the way to check if the user did selected a row.

However, this method is fired **only when the picker "stop spinning"**.

```
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // Here you run your code.
}
```

Hope that helps.